# Using cloud function to denormalize firestore data issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using many cloud function trigger and admin sdk to do multi-path update.I don't want to do too much multi-path update in client cause it will make firestore rules very complex and firestore rules also have document access call limits.So I decide to using cloud function to do most denomorlization stuff.

There is how one of my function work.

1. cloud function triggered at profiles/{userId}
2. and i using .get to load multi-path update needed paths at 
   profilesPaths/{userId}
3. set writebatch.update on those paths
4. writebatch.commit()

And I think there have a problem.cloud function is asynchronous right?.So when function are running to step 3 And at the same moment a client delete one of update path from cf already loaded document at profilesPaths/{userId} (already loaded at step 2).and now cloud function loaded document is not the latest version.Will this happend? or i should using transactions to lock those documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Cloud Functions run asynchronous, and possibly in parallel.  You should be using [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to make sure that updates are consistent among all the clients that are trying to modify them concurrently.